# How to solve, finding two of each link (Beautifulsoup, python)

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, href

Im using beautifulsoup4 to parse a webpage and collect all the href values using this code

```
    #Collect links from 'new' page
pageRequest = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/shirts')
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageRequest.content, "html.parser")
links = soup.select("div.turbolink_scroller a")

allProductInfo = soup.find_all("a", class_="name-link")
print allProductInfo

linksList1 = []
for href in allProductInfo:
    linksList1.append(href.get('href'))

print(linksList1)
```

linksList1 prints two of each link. I believe this is happening as its taking the link from the title as well as the item colour. I have tried a few things but cannot get BS to only parse the title link, and have a list of one of each link instead of two. I imagine its something real simple but im missing it. Thanks in advance

Comment: make linksList1 a set() instead of list()

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
alldiv = soup.findAll("div", {"class":"inner-article"})
for div in alldiv:
    linkList1.append(div.h1.a['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the result without getting duplicate results
(also using set() may be a good idea as @Tarum Gupta)
But I changed the way you crawl

```
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Collect links from 'new' page
pageRequest = requests.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/shirts')
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageRequest.content, "html.parser")
links = soup.select("div.turbolink_scroller a")

# Gets all divs with class of inner-article then search for a with name-link class
that is inside an h1 tag
allProductInfo = soup.select("div.inner-article h1 a.name-link")
# print (allProductInfo)

linksList1 = []
for href in allProductInfo:
    linksList1.append(href.get('href'))

print(linksList1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set(linksList1)        # use set() to remove duplicate link
list(set(linksList1))  # use list() convert set to list if you need
```